# Weird font anti-aliasing in view-based NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, macos, text, nsoutlineview, osx-lion

I'm currently working on an app that uses Lion's new view-based `NSOutlineView`. The problem I've ran into, however, is that I don't get nice subpixel anti-aliasing. As a result, the text doesn't appear as smooth as one would expect on Mac OS X.

Here are two screenshots to illustrate the issue. Finder (proper text rendering) on the left, my app on the right.

[image: Finder]
[image: My App]

Any idea what could cause that issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have your cell views, your outline view or its enclosing scroll view to be layer backed? The issue here is the text on the right is not sub pixel aliased, which happens when you set a view to be layer backed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was indeed the problem!