# Layer-backed NSView animation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, nstableview

I have a certain NSView that I want to animate, but that NSView has a NSTableView inside which does not display correclty when the view is layer-backed (which in turn is nececessary to animate a view). So my answer was to make the view layer-backed right before animating, and then when the animation was done remove the layer, like this:

```
[animatingView setWantsLayer: YES];

[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];

[[animatingView animator] animateSomething];

[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler: ^{
    [animatingView setWantsLayer: NO];
}];

[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

However, with this code the view doesn't animate at all. I found that if I remove the `[animatingView setWantsLayer: NO];` line it animates just right, but then the table view doesn't display correctly (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968312/weird-font-anti-aliasing-in-view-based-nsoutlineview) question for an example of one of the problems).

So, my question is: how do I solve this? I want to animate a view, but I want tables to display properly, and this workaround doesn't work. And I don't get why...

Answer (score 2):

Once you make NSView layer-backed it cannot be reverted.

I suggest you to try to make your NSTableView a sibling of the layer-backed view, not a child.

Comment: But the view has to contain the table, that's the idea. The view contains the table, some buttons and some textfields, and I want to animate them all and at the same time, and it's not an option to animate them one by one.

Comment: @Alex I agree. But unfortunately you just faced a bug and you need to find workaround. You have to either hack your NSTableView to work correctly on layer-backed superview or hack the animation process.

Comment: Well, you have a point, of course. There's still something I don't understand: why doesn't the code above result in an animation? I mean, I'm setting the view to be layer-backed, then I'm animating it, and then in the end I'm making it not layer-backed, but that doesn't do anything acording to you, so why doesn't it animate? Like I said in the question, if I remove the line in the completion handler it animates, so it would seem that line does make a difference. How come?

Comment: @Alex You should set completion block before you add animations.

Comment: I found out that what I want to do is possible. On Finder's settings window on the third tab there's a table view which animates (fades in) when that third tab is selected. See this animated gif: http://goo.gl/hny1C Note how the background of the table is while animating compared to how it is after the animation. A wrong (repeated) gradient for source-list-type tableviews is a sign that the table is layer-backed. So it *is* layer-backed for the animation (of course). But then the gradient goes back to normal! So it **isn't** layer-backed after the animation. How can I reproduce this?

Comment: Maybe they draw layer-backed version of the view during animation and then replace it with normal one afterwards.